# Existing binary executable not found inside kubernetes mounted volume in Docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have mounted a binary (tini init) to the `/executables` mountPath. The docker image is `busybox:latest`

Mounting:

```
- name: executables
  mountPath: /executables
```

Volume creation:

```
- name: executables
  emptyDir: {}
```

I ran a sidecar container that adds the `tini` binary to this volume.

inside the `/executables` directory after attaching to the container:

```sh
/executables # ls
tini
/executables # pwd
/executables
/executables # ls
tini
/executables # ./tini 
sh: ./tini: not found
/executables #
```

Everything's alright but when I try executing it, it shows `not found` when the file is right there! driving me nuts. Please help!

Comment: Maybe duplicate with this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/why-does-sh-say-not-found-when-its-definitely-there

Comment: What does your tini init do? What's the content? how did you build it?

Comment: @Rico it's just https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases

Comment: @Sylwit interesting, afaik I used busybox uclibc (latest) versions for both the sidecar and the actual container. Thanks for the link, might be something related

Comment: The sidecar just downloaded the binary, it is working on an alpine image but not with the busybox one. I'll look into it more.

Comment: yeah, it's probably busybox if it works with alpine

Comment: Generally you want to build a custom image if you want to do the sort of thing.  Better still, busybox contains an **init**(8) and I’d just use that one.  (What happens if you need to restart all of your nodes, and also GitHub is down, so pods can’t start up?)

Answer (score 2):

Solved this using a static build for the binary, turns out it's very relevant to this:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/why-does-sh-say-not-found-when-its-definitely-there

Answer (score 0):

If you just download the binary you have change the permission and do a `chmod +x tini` before try to launch it.